# turf.booleanOverlap unexpected result

Tags: javascript, geospatial, polygon, spatial, turfjs

I am having this polygon:

```
const polygon = JSON.parse('{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[6.26950853,50.72473626],[6.26953794,50.72468996],[6.2695546,50.7246512],[6.26949169,50.72468741],[6.26948194,50.72469389],[6.26946154,50.72470787],[6.26949172,50.72474162],[6.26950853,50.72473626]]]}}');
```

and this bounding box:

```
const bbox = JSON.parse('{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[6.511887823915231,50.950514414615334],[6.512896634823051,50.53594214902105],[5.98503728350704,50.53594214902105],[5.98604609441486,50.950514414615334],[6.511887823915231,50.950514414615334]]]}}');
```

I want to know if the polygon is intesecting the bounding box

I use [booleanOverlap](http://turfjs.org/docs#booleanOverlap,) from [turf.js](http://turfjs.org/) for that.

```
turf.booleanOverlap(polygon, bbox);
```

It returns `false`.

Why is that? That definetly is within the bounding box.

Answer (score 4):

Ah, Ive got it. 
The documentation says

"Compares two geometries of the same dimension and returns true if their intersection set results in a geometry different from both but of the same dimension. [...]"

My polygon is completely withing the bounding box. As far as I know an *intersection* (as the documentation says) *encompasses* a polygon that is within another polygon. What `booleanOverlap` does is only checking whether it overlaps or not. I think documentation is a little missleading here because it lets users think that `booleanOverlap` includes a within.